# node.js: How can I write a "find or create" static method on my user model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to write a "find or create" static method on my user model - pretty much like an upsert but where the pre-save hook will also run.

This is my user model:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt-nodejs'));

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    e:  { type: String, required: true, trim: true, index: { unique: true } },
    fb: { type: String, required: true },
    ap: { type: String, required: true },
    f:  { type: String, required: true },
    l:  { type: String, required: true }
});

// Execute before each user.save() call
userSchema.pre('save', function(callback) {
    bcrypt.genSaltAsync(5)
    .then(function (salt) {
        return bcrypt.hash(this.fb, salt, null);
    })
    .then(function (hash) {
        user.fb = hash;
    })
    .then(function (){
        return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(5);
    })
    .then(function (salt) {
        return bcrypt.hash(this.ap, salt, null);
    })
    .then(function (hash) {
        user.ap = hash;
    })
    .then(function () {
        callback();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        callback(err);
    });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I'm wanting it to do something like this, but nothing I try is working:

```
userSchema.statics.FindOrCreate(function(json) {
    return this.findOne({e: json.email}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return err;
        if(user) return user;
        // return new user
    });
});
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend skipping Mongoose and using mongodb-promise with async/await and babel.  It will be much simpler and look something like this:

```
// imports, and connect to db
//...
export async function save(user) {
  // qry=... upd=...
  let salt = await bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10);
  // user.hash=
  let res = await mongo.update(qry,upd,{upsert:true});
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hooks (mongoose middleware):

```
schema.post('find', function(result) {
    // if there is no result
    // create new document
});
```